# Finding text and then replacing on next line

Tags: excel, vba

I was previously using a macro which found the first blank line in a workbook and then put tags in the next 9 columns. This was working well for a project however i've now encountered issues in that macro doesn't always find the exact blank row i want (maybe because of formatting i'm not sure)

This was my code for that idea:

```
Sub SetupTags(pintNumFeatures As Integer, pintNumRecords As Integer, pintSubGroupSize As Integer)

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long
Dim lngTotal As Long
Dim lngCell As Long
Dim lngDataRow As Long
Dim lngDataCol As Long
Dim lngFirstRow As Long

lngFirstRow = FindFirstBlankRow
lngRow = lngFirstRow
lngCol = 9
lngTotal = pintNumFeatures * pintNumRecords
lngDataCol = 1
lngDataRow = 1

For lngCell = 1 To lngTotal
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, lngCol).Value = "[act]{rowcol:" & lngDataRow & "," & lngDataCol & "}"
  lngCol = lngCol + 1
  
  If lngCol > 13 Then
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
    lngCol = 9
  End If
  
  lngDataRow = lngDataRow + 1
  If lngDataRow > pintNumRecords Then
    lngDataCol = lngDataCol + 1
    lngDataRow = 1
  End If
Next lngCell

'now figure out the column specific stuff
Dim intPartRows As Integer
Dim intPartRow As Integer
Dim intFeature As Integer
Dim intRecordNumber As Integer

intPartRows = CInt(pintNumRecords / 5)
lngRow = lngFirstRow
lngCol = 1
intRecordNumber = 1

For intFeature = 1 To pintNumFeatures
  For intPartRow = 0 To intPartRows - 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = "[part_" & intFeature & "]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "[dim_" & intFeature & "]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 3).Value = "[date]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 4).Value = "[date]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 5).Formula = "=AVERAGE(I" & lngRow & ":M" & lngRow & ")"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 6).Formula = "=MAX(I" & lngRow & ":M" & lngRow & ") - MIN(I" & lngRow & ":M" & lngRow & ")"
        
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 14).Value = "[tf1]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 15).Value = "[tf2]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 16).Value = "[tf3]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 17).Value = "[tf4]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 18).Value = "[tf5]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 19).Value = "[tf6]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 20).Value = "[tf7]{Row:" & intRecordNumber & "}"

    
    
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
    intRecordNumber = intRecordNumber + 5
  Next intPartRow
Next intFeature







End Sub
Function FindFirstBlankRow() As Long
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngFound As Long

'we need to check for blanks and not shaded to determine the actual last used row since the xlSpecialCells is not always accurate
'change this for each stage maybe 27 is the first empty row of stage 2 onwards we cannot have any empty rows passed this point'
For lngRow = 27 To 1000
  If Sheet1.Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "" Then
    lngFound = lngRow
    Exit For
  End If
Next lngRow

FindFirstBlankRow = lngFound

End Function

Sub ReAddTags() 'pintNumFeatures As Integer, pintNumRecords As Integer, pintSubGroupSize As Integer)

Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngFirstRow As Long

lngFirstRow = FindFirstBlankRow
lngRow = lngFirstRow

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 1).Value = "[All Feature Numbers]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 2).Value = "[ALL EXTRA INFO]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 4).Value = "[ALLLABELS]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 6).Value = "[allnoms]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 7).Value = "[FEATURE_SOURCES]"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(lngRow, 9).Value = "[ACTROWS]"



End Sub
```

So i need to approach it a different way i have constant across the workbook of the word "Sequence" it always sits 1 line above the where i want to reintroduce these tags so i'm looking for something like this

•   Find the next Sequence Text (this is always 1 line above where I want to put the tags back in)
•   Then move one line below and add the tags back in
•   There would need to be some kind of IF statement saying that if there is text in this line then skip to the next sequence text (this would stop it putting tags back into stages that have already been populated with data)

I can find some other code which does a find and replace but nothing as advanced to skip a line and also populate this IF statement

```
Sub test()

Dim rngColumn       As Range
Dim rngCell         As Range

Set rngColumn = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("H")
For Each rngCell In rngColumn.Cells
    If Trim(rngCell) <> "" Then
        If Trim(rngCell) = "815" Then
            rngCell.Value = "'0815"
        End If
    End If
Next rngCell

Set rngColumn = Nothing
Set rngCell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For moving to the next available row in a column you could use:

```
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
```